# Merge appends extra values due to longer column in one dataset?

Tags: r, merge

I try to merge two data frames based on a identifier column:

```
NEI <- merge(data, classification, by = "SCC", )
```

where data is an original data file with some measurements that are identified by "SCC", and a classification file with corresponding names for the "SCC" value. For example, SCC code 10010203 corresponds to "Industrial wastewater".

However, the list of classifications for SCC codes is more extensive than there are measurements / SCC's in the original data file. As such, when the files are merged, at the end of the NEI data frame, the non-overlapping SCC codes from the classification file are appended in front of the SCC value that corresponds to the measurement and the corresponding name (which is why I wanted to merge the files).

```
> head(NEI)
   SCC  fips Pollutant Emissions  type year                                               Short.Name
1 10100101 34017  PM25-PRI   898.421 POINT 1999 Ext Comb /Electric Gen /Anthracite Coal /Pulverized Coal

> tail(NEI)
         SCC  fips Pollutant Emissions  type year                                                                 Short.Name
6497646 68510001 47163  PM25-PRI   2.0e-02 POINT 2005                                           Phthalate Plasticizer Production
```

The "6497646" value that is at the tail end of the NEI frame, should not be added. As I explained before, I think this is because the files are merged for both "SCC" variables in both files, and the SCC list is longer in the classification / index file.

How can I ensure that only the SCC codes from the measurements file are merged into the new frame?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think if you run `nrow(NEI)`, you'll get `6497646`. If so, it's just the corresponding row number. You don't need to worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

Those numbers are just rownames and if you don't want them, you can drop all rownames.

```
rownames(NEI) <- NULL
```

Comment: Great, sorry! Thanks.